# On iOS, why can UIGestureRecognizer be instantiated, if it is an abstract class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, abstract-class

The following code using [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecog = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                         initWithTarget:self 
                                         action:@selector(handletap:)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecog];
```

can actually compile and run.  I thought [abstract class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_class) cannot be instantiated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abstract classes are not a language feature in Objective-C (unlike Java, for example), so it isn't something the compiler could enforce.

When a class is marked as abstract in the documentation, it is just a hint how it is *intended* to be used, but neither the runtime, nor the compiler will actually prevent you from instantiating it directly.

The section on [abstract classes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-BAJCCBHC) in the Objective-C Programming Language Guide actually states that `NSView` is an example of an abstract class that you may sometimes use without subclassing, so the concept as such is not as strict as in other languages/frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for omz's answer.  This is the related excerpt from Apple's documentation:

> Abstract Classes
>
> Some classes are designed only or primarily so that other classes can
>   inherit from them. These abstract classes group methods and instance
>   variables that can be used by a number of subclasses into a common
>   definition. The abstract class is typically incomplete by itself, but
>   contains useful code that reduces the implementation burden of its
>   subclasses. (Because abstract classes must have subclasses to be
>   useful, they’re sometimes also called abstract superclasses.)
>
> Unlike some other languages, Objective-C does not have syntax to mark
>   classes as abstract, nor does it prevent you from creating an instance
>   of an abstract class.
>
> The NSObject class is the canonical example of an abstract class in
>   Cocoa. You never use instances of the NSObject class in an
>   application—it wouldn’t be good for anything; it would be a generic
>   object with the ability to do nothing in particular.
>
> The NSView class, on the other hand, provides an example of an
>   abstract class, instances of which you might occasionally use
>   directly.
>
> Abstract classes often contain code that helps define the structure of
>   an application. When you create subclasses of these classes, instances
>   of your new classes fit effortlessly into the application structure
>   and work automatically with other objects.